# Модуль для rsa шифрования node js

Tags: node.js, rsa

Посоветуйте нормальный модуль, без OpenSsl, где генерируется закрытый и открытый ключи шифрования и шифруются по открытому, а шифруется по закрытому

Comment: TLS/HTTPS вас чем не устроили?

Comment: https ставится на домен как я знаю, а это целая морока регистрировать его

Comment: Чем вам openssl(crypto) не угодил?

Comment: На всякий случай https://habrahabr.ru/post/181372/

Comment: Пытаюсь установить библиотеку ursa при помощи npm, но постоянно вылетает ошибка. Что делать?

Comment: Непонятна какова цель этого действа, что вас не устраивает стандартный tls с самоподписанным сертификатом https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html

Answer (score 0):

Я использую **keygrip**:

> Keygrip is a node.js module for signing and verifying data (such as cookies or URLs) through a rotating credential system, in which new server keys can be added and old ones removed regularly, without invalidating client credentials.